# crude spoke tension gauge

Tags: torque, tools

Standard bicycle spoke tensiometers are too large for use with small wheels, the kind used on recumbent bikes and folding bikes. Could a small adjustable or beam-style torque wrench be used to gauge spoke tension with something like the apparatus in this sketch, a socket with a couple of J-bend spokes welded to it?

[image: crude spoke tension gauge]

Comment: The best way to crudely measure spoke tension is to pluck them and listen to the pitch of the note. www.sheldonbrown.com/spoke-pitch.html

Comment: Your scheme won't let you determine which spoke is the problem.

Comment: @Transistor: That is true if we are working on an already strung wheel with all of its spokes tensioned, but not if we are tensioning a new wheel for the first time, where we start with all spokes untensioned.

Comment: I've built a couple of wheels and I don't know how you could measure tension until all the spokes are reasonably well tensioned. At a minimum you would need two spokes taut on each diametrically opposite side of the hub and on each flange - eight altogether - but applying any tension to these would pull the wheel into an oval. Have you another scheme?

Comment: @Transistor: No expertise here, since I've built only a couple of wheels myself, following examples on Youtube, where the spokes are laced loosely, a thread visible at the nipple, and then tightened up in sequence moving around the rim. To prevent rim distortion when using this gizmo, spoke-pairs could be placed on both flanges at approximately 12, 3, 6, and 9 o'clock, and the pairs on each flange could then be tightened a tad, in sequence, 12, 3, 6, 9, repeating that process until all 8 pairs have reached proper tension. The remaining gaps could be filled in, alternating quadrants and sides.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift  I am trying this musical approach now. My 260mm plain spokes are only at 350Hz (per tuning fork app) and feel quite taut. I'm going to spring for a tensiometer before making them any tauter.